# SSL_write reports success but fails in Safari

Tags: c++, sockets, safari, openssl

I have my own implementation of a webserver that utilizes openssl.

I am using the blocking version of `SSL_write` to transmit data and the latest Safari on OSX.

My logic is as follows:

```
num_bytes = 0;
while( num_bytes < bytes_to_send) {
  int n = SSL_write(...);
  if (n <= 0) {
     ... // Handle error, break loop
  }
  num_bytes += n;
}
// Close the socket
```

There is an infrequent problem I am encountering where Safari reports `Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.`

When I check the resource in the developer pane under Safari, it shows that there were less bytes received than expected.

I have debugged my code and determined `SSL_write` is reporting that all bytes were transferred before I close the connection.

When I do not close the connection, this bug no longer occurs.

This leads me to the following conclusion:

`SSL_write` incorrectly reports a number of bytes were successfully transferred before it has actually occurred, and that closing the connection immediately after cuts the transfer short.

Am I correct, or is there a detail about `SSL_write` that I am missing?

Update:

After examining the way I process `SSL_shutdown`, I am seeing a couple of `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` errors being reported. This may or may not have anything to do with my problem since these errors are not directly returned after the affected http transfers. Strangely, during the affected http transfers no errors are reported from `SSL_shutdown` other than the retry error for blocking calls.

Shutdown Code

```
// First shutdown SSL
SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
if (SSL_shutdown(ssl) == 0) {
  // Call SSL Shutdown again
  SSL_shutdown(ssl);
}
SSL_free(ssl);

// Now shutdown port
struct linger linger;
linger.l_onoff = 1;
linger.l_linger = 10;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char *)&linger,
           sizeof(linger));

shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR);
while(recv(...) > 0) { }
closesocket(socket);
```

Update #2

I set up wireshark with ssl decryption to capture the error. Here is what it looks like:
[image: Safari Error Message: PatientSearch.js]
[image: Wireshark Capture: See PatientSearch.js Successfully Transferred]

Notice the first green line, which shows the HTTP request from Safari for `PatientSearch.js` . Now the second green line shows the HTTP response from my webserver. This response contains the file in its entirety, followed by the disconnection protocol.

Update #3

This is getting more mysterious by the second. After examining a wireshark trace for a successful transfer, and there is no difference in the protocol pattern in the successful transfer vs the broken transfer. Completely confused now.

Comment: Given that it works when you keep the connection open my guess is that the bug is actually elsewhere, i.e. that you don't read the request from the client properly before closing the socket. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33947985/3081018.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich after reading your comment I went back and double checked my header processing code and confirmed that the entire request is, in fact, retrieved from the socket. I read out/printed the entire HTTP header, returned the data to the client using SSL_write, and then closed the socket. Safari is still broken on an intermittent basis after doing so.

Comment: can you post your shutdown code? Both for SSL and for the underlying socket?

Comment: @hofan41: I know that Safari on mobile devices uses [HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) by default, and that was causing problems with an HTTP server I once implemented. Closing the socket after sending a response caused subsequent requests still in the pipeline to fail and Safari was not happy about that. Maybe Safari for OSX suffers from a similar issue?

Comment: @hofan41: Is your server using HTTP 1.0 or 1.1? Is your server handing [HTTP keepalive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) requests? Are you sending a `Connection: close` header in your response before closing the socket?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had checked for the possibility of this being an HTTP pipelining problem, and I didn't see any extra data waiting for me on the socket so I do not believe that is the problem. The server is using HTTP 1.1 and it is sending the `Connection: close` header in the response right before closing the socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau since my server is using HTTP 1.1 , could it be by responding to an http request with keep-alive set to `close` it causes safari to crap out? Maybe safari assumes all HTTP 1.1 requests are persistent and expects only an idle timeout condition to cause them to be closed?

Comment: HTTP keepalive is negotiated. It is perfectly valid for the server to decide to close a connection that the client requests to be persistent, as long as it reports the decision in the response.

Answer (score 2):

Your send loop is not keeping track of the number of sent bytes correctly. It should look more like this instead:

```
unsigned char *data = ...;
while (bytes_to_send > 0) {
  int num_sent = SSL_write(ssl, data, bytes_to_send);
  if (num_sent <= 0) {
    // handle error as needed...
    break;
  }
  data += num_sent;
  bytes_to_send -= num_sent;
}
// Close the socket
```

Or this:

```
unsigned char *data = ...;
int num_total_sent = 0;
while (num_total_sent < bytes_to_send) {
  int num_sent = SSL_write(ssl, &data[num_total_sent], bytes_to_send - num_total_sent);
  if (num_sent <= 0) {
    // handle error as needed...
    break;
  }
  num_total_sent += num_sent;
}
// Close the socket
```

---

Update:

> SSL_write incorrectly reports a number of bytes were successfully transferred before it has actually occurred

The return value reports the number of bytes it accepted from you.  That does not guarantee that those bytes were actually transmitted yet.  They are encrypted and used to create an outgoing SSL frame, which is sitting in the underlying socket's outbound buffer waiting for the kernel to actually transmit it in the background.  That transmission may take some time, especially if the Nagle algorithm is enabled on the socket (which it usually is by default).

> closing the connection immediately after cuts the transfer short.

That is possible, depending on how you are closing the connection, how the socket's linger option is configured, etc.  By default, closing a socket gracefully should allow the kernel to take a few extra moments in the background to write out any pending data before it then actually closes the connection.  You usually have to take extra measures to change that behavior.

Comment: Apologies for not posting my pseudo code correctly. I am, in fact, using a loop quite similar to the ones you have posted. I have updated my question to more accurately reflect my loop.